# jQuery Ajax Problems

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making a Greasemonkey script for the Runecape forums (Yes runescape! :p) and I'm trying to make something to look up stats.

```
$('.rssc_view_stats').click(function(){
        var this_username = $(this).attr('rel');            
        var stats_box = '<div id="stats_box"></div>';   
        //alert('looking for the stats of' + this_username);
        $(this).after(stats_box);

        $('#stats_box').load('http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player='+this_username);
    });
```

But it just doesn't work. I looked at the response in Firebug but the response is blank and it gave me a 501 Not implemented error. Also in firebug where it says either POST or GET it says OPTIONS.

Why is it doing this?

I thought mabey its the fact that ajax doesn't work across different domains but this is just a different sub-domain and I think Greasemonkey overrides that anyway.

Comment: If you try to open the URL being passed to load in a browser, does it do what you expect?

Comment: @inkedmn yep it's fine in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I can't do it with jQuery, I have to use a greasemonkey function.

http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/api/gm_xmlhttprequest.html

Answer (score 0):

Try delete:

```
http://hiscore.runescape.com/
```

from address in load function.